# Removing GRUB when migrating to SSD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, grub, disk-cloning

I have an SSD that I would like to migrate windows to. It previously had Ubuntu installed. After reformatting the hardrive, then using cloning software to clone the windows onto it, I tried to boot to the new hard drive. I got a grub rescue command prompt. I then created windows repair disk, and it did not recognize the disk as a windows partition. I then tried the steps found in this youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1QpN9IWSoc

```
set boot=(hd0,msdos1)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
insmod normal
```

When I tried to run insmod normal, got an unknown filetype error.

I have tried using multiple cloning softwares, and reformatting a bunch of times. How is grub still on this?! and how do i get windows running?

Comment: reformat the **whole** disk and not just the ubuntu partition, should wipe out GRUB completely. After that you can clone your windows partitions / whole disk from the windows drive and _voila_, you should now have the windows bootloader (usually invisible) instead.

Comment: I did reformat the whole disk, that's why i'm confused as to how it is still there. Seems impossible that it would still show up

Comment: If you formatted the whole disk grub wouldn't be there, i would get a live CD boot from that and delete every partition on the disk and format - ubuntu sometimes creates a ~100MB boot partition to keep grub in

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the master boot record.  You can use fixmbr or from dos, fdisk /mbr - see [Does the fixmbr command repair the Master Boot Code only or it repairs the Master Partition Table, too?](https://superuser.com/questions/721558/does-the-fixmbr-command-repair-the-master-boot-code-only-or-it-repairs-the-maste)